# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a new table that converts data from an existing command I have written below, but dataframe work does not seem to accept '>' symbol or recognize it. I tried defining both tables as INT and still encountered the same problem.

[image]

Should I define the table as NP rather than DF? and If I chose to still keep the DF command how to overcome the challenge of using greater than or less than while using DF still?

Comment: Why are you storing most numerical values as strings?

Comment: Also, please post your code as text, not just a link to an image.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The column `Area square miles` contains strings, so you can't compare them to `500`

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

comes from the tries of

```
"1000" > 500
```

---

Fix that either

- in `cities` use int and float type, not strings
- in the df

  ```
  df["Area square miles"] = df["Area square miles"].astype(int)
  ```